# How do I get preg_match to output a specific part of a URL?

Tags: regex, preg-match

Okay, if I have the URL `http://hello.com/api/thispart.php`

How to I get the preg_match() function to select just `thispart`

So far I am looking at

```
preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@', "http://hello.com/api/thispart.php", $matches)
echo " <br>Domain name is: $matches[0] <br>";
echo " <br>Domain name is: $matches[1];
```

The output is

```
Domain name is: http://hello.com

Domain name is: hello.com
```

But I just want it to output `thispart`

Answer (score 0):

any reason you can't use [basename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php), and then [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) at the dot?

Comment: This almost works. When I do this it give thispart followed by a new line character, so it cannot be used for comparisons.